# R: Filling a polygon with a solid color and lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently creating a state map using ggplot and am having some trouble figuring out how to add both lines and color to a polygon within the map conditionally. I have a variable "lines" within my data set. When lines==1, I want the associated polygons to be filled with a color (this is already set) as well as lines. The following is my code:

```
map_theme_main <- theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
                        panel.border = element_rect(color="white", fill=NA, size=rel(1)),
                        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
                        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
                        plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = .5),
                        plot.caption = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 0),
                        #legend.position = "bottom",
                        #legend.justification = c(0,0),
                        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
                        legend.position = "right",
                        legend.title = element_text(size = 14),
                        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                        panel.grid = element_blank(),
                        legend.key.size = unit(.6, 'cm'),
                        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'white'))


main<-ggplot(data = zcta_ss_DF, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group, fill =bin)) + geom_polygon() + geom_path(size = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual('', values = colors, drop = F) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -117), ylim = c(45, 49)) + 
  ggtitle("Total Sample Size By ZCTA") +
  map_theme_main + guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol=1, title.theme = element_text(size=8)))

main <- main + theme(legend.key = element_rect(color="black"))
```

How would I alter the above code to add on the layer of lines where the variable "lines"==1?

Comment: Could you please add a [reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear what you refer to as "lines" and since there is no reproducible example, I "borrowed" from `{maps}`. But if you adapt the code to your case, it should get you going. For presentation reasons, I skipped the theme-ing you applied.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

my_map <- map_data("state")    # get a state-level world map

#----------------- basic plot -------------------------
ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon( data=my_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)
                , color="black"     # color defines the "line" of the polygon
                , fill="lightblue"  # fill gives the fill color of the polygon
                ) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -117), ylim = c(45, 49)) +
    ggtitle("Total Sample Size By ZCTA")
```

[image: basic ggplot map of Washington]

Note what `color` and `fill` control inside the `geom_polygon()` call.

If you want to change the fill color conditionally, we can add this "differentiator" as a column to our map dataframe. You can add this as a categorical variable to the dataframe. I use a simplistic TRUE/FALSE (aka binary categorical variable). In the `scale_fill_manual()` control the sequence of colours of your categories. What is important is that `fill` is now a variable for which you apply an "aesthetic mapping". Thus, it needs to go into the `aes()`!
Arguably, my colour choice could be improved. :)

```
my_map <- my_map %>% 
   mutate(my_color = ifelse(region == "washington", TRUE, FALSE)  # adding a simple categorical variable
   ) 

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = my_map 
               , aes( x=long, y=lat, group=group
#--------------------- include mapping for fill --------------------------------------
                     ,fill = my_color)                      # fill is now an aesthetic
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
               , color="black" 
                ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","lightblue")) +     # more control over fill
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -117), ylim = c(45, 49)) +
  ggtitle("Total Sample Size By ZCTA")
```

[image]

With this in the back pocket, you can now work on the polygon lines (aka boundaries).
The `color` parameter defines the line color. If you want to "map" it, you can do this conditionally in a similar way. I apply the same principle to the line-color and line-width, i.e. `size`.
As I lack of creativity, I use the categorical variable `my_color` created above. Obviously, you can supply different values or another variable here.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = my_map 
               , aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = my_color
#------------------ now color and size get included in the mapping -------------
               , color= my_color
               , size = my_color) 
#--------------------------------------------- and supplied with a categorical variable
                ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","lightblue")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -117), ylim = c(45, 49)) +
  ggtitle("Total Sample Size By ZCTA")
```

This gets you the following:

[image]

Work out how the sequence of your color and size definitions work.

Hope this is what you had in mind.
Obviously, you can now add "additional lines" by adding additional layers to your plot ... but for this you will have to clarify your question or what you want to achieve.

**amendment based on comment**: if you want to add "texture" type of fills, there is now a cool package `{ggpattern}` that takes away quite some of the hassle. Check out the package web-page https://statisticsglobe.com/ggpattern-r-package.
Building on our example I push the `pattern_fill` into the `aes()` mapping to hook it up with a variable (re-using the my_color categorical variable, but pick what you need) and define a 'static' fill-colour outside the  `aes()`.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon_pattern(data = my_map 
                 , aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = my_color
                       #------------------ now color and size get included in the mapping -------------
                       , color= my_color
                       , size = my_color 
                 #-------------------------- and supplied with a categorical variable
                       , pattern = my_color) # adding a mapping for the pattern
                 ,pattern_fill = "black"     # provide a static pattern fill color
                 #-------------------------- end of ggpattern/fill add-ons
    ) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("yellow","lightblue")) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-125, -117), ylim = c(45, 49)) +
    ggtitle("Total Sample Size By ZCTA")
```

This results in:
[image: figure with pattern fill]

As mentioned above you can be more creative with the assignment of categorical variables to control the fill pattern, colour, and size. Please bear with me that I opted for doing this once ... and very simplistic. Play around with the number of effects (categories) you need to adapt to your use case.

Comment: This is really helpful! I did not explain my question too well, but what I mean by "lines" is cross hatching or diagonal lines going through the entirety of a polygon conditionally on top of a color that is already set. I believe this would be referred to as "texture", but unsure. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, bziggy. It was fun adding this. As usual / often. The question is not can it be done, but what (newer) package can help :). There are other solutions when you work with `geom_sf()` or other graphics packages. But I am not an expert and would have to google myself on SO. All the best!